# How to return a specific value type in a promise using Angular/Typescript

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm stuck on something that I think should be pretty simple.  We have a child component that accepts an input as such:

```
@Input() accessories: { [key: string]: Accessory };
```

And when the component is initialzed the template is able to read and display the values but we also need them in the component but they're not available.  So we're trying to use setTimeout to force a change:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  var resultArray = this.accessories;

  if (this.accessories!= undefined) {
        accessories.forEach(x =>
            Object.keys(this.accessories).findIndex(key => {
                if (this.accessories[key].accessoryId == x.accessoryId && this.accessories [key].code == "RECORD") {
                    this.isRecord= true;
                }
            }))}}, 2000);
```

But it still fires after we need it.  I'm trying to implement a promise, which I haven't used before, so looking for some guidance on how to get this variable when it's available.  I'm trying to wait for the result before continuing with the process.

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a Promise like this:

```
function foo() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const returnValue = 'foo';
      resolve(returnValue);
    }, 2000);
  });
}

function main() {
  foo().then(res => console.log(res)); // 'foo'
}
```

Comment: I follow the flow, can you help me incorporate my code?  I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do in the resolve.

Comment: The problem is not that you need a Promise, but that you don't know when your Input data is passed to the child component. If you want to catch this moment, use the changes lifecycle : https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/detect-input-property-changes-ngonchanges-setters

Comment: It's passed in when the parent form loads, and displays on the template, but I'm trying to find a way to force the component to be able to read it.